# How to splice out data from an array that has a matching key or name with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okay so I have a project I am working on. It uses a Magic the Gathering API and displays cards on a screen. I have a search component on the page that works with the name. I have it set up so that if the card does not contain an imageUrl it does not display on the page. Now I want to remove card duplicates that are displayed because there are different reprints of them. basically every card as a unique key to them. here is my component that contains the fetch. One more thing to note I am not using any OOP.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CardList from "./CardList";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";



function DeckBuilder() {
const [input, setInput] = useState('');
const [mtgCardsList, setMtgCardsList] = useState();


const fetchData = async (searchInput) => {
return await fetch(`https://api.magicthegathering.io/v1/cards?name=${searchInput}`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    data.cards.forEach((card, i) => {
        if (!card.imageUrl){
          data.cards.splice(i)
        }
        setMtgCardsList(data.cards)
    })

    
})
}

const updateInput = async (input) => {
    setInput(input);
    await fetchData(input);
}

useEffect( () => {fetchData("")}, []);

    return( <div>  
              <SearchBar input={input} onChange={updateInput}/>
                <div className="cardcontainer">
                    <CardList mtgCardsList={mtgCardsList}/>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}

export default DeckBuilder;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Set` of the unique card keys, so that each key only appears once then iterate through your cards and check if the unique id exists in the Set, if it does add it to a temporary array and delete the key from the Set. Eventually there will be no more keys in the Set and you will have your temporary array filled with one of each card.